# Add a JScrollPane to avoid distortion of components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, scroll, jscrollpane

I am trying to make a variable size interface. However, currently, if the size of all components is greater than the dimension of the window, then those begin to
distort ! Therefore, I would like to add a JScrollPane to be displayed when the window size is no longer sufficient, in order to avoid this distortion.
I just started by adding a JScrollPane (as shown on the code bellow), but it does not seem to work, and I am not sure what to change now.

```
JScrollPane myScrollPane = new JScrollPane();
myWindow.getContentPane().add(myScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

**EDIT 1**: here is a simple example of what I have tried:

```
static void one(String[] ari, JLabel sess_nb, Box boxy, long[] res){
    int p;
    int length = ari.length;
    Border cadre = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black);
    Font police = new Font("Monospaced 13", Font.BOLD, 18);
    Font police1 = new Font("Monospaced 13", Font.BOLD, 15);
    Font font = new Font("Monospaced 13", Font.ITALIC, 13);
    for (p=0;p<length;p++){
        Box boxz = Box.createVerticalBox();
        JLabel Rate = new JLabel("Rating Group "+r);
        JLabel rg_reser = new JLabel();
        JLabel switsh = new JLabel("1");
        JLabel reser = new JLabel(); //in this label the resrvation for each update and each rating group will be stocked
        JLabel consump = new JLabel(); //in this label will be stocked the consumption
        //----------------------------------------------------

        //choice of MB or kB
        JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
        combo.addItem("Megabytes");
        combo.addItem("Bytes");
        combo.addItem("kilobytes");
        combo.addItem("Gigabytes");
        JLabel upload = new JLabel("Upload consumption:");
        JTextField upload_entry = new JTextField("7.5");
        JLabel download = new JLabel("Download consumption:");
        JTextField download_entry = new JTextField("7.5");
        JTextField total_entry = new JTextField();
        JLabel total = new JLabel("Total consumption:");
        JButton rg = new JButton("Next");
        JLabel update = new JLabel("Result here");
        boxz.add(Rate);
        boxz.add(total);
        boxz.add(total_entry);
        boxz.add(upload);
        boxz.add(upload_entry);
        boxz.add(download);
        boxz.add(download_entry);
        boxz.add(combo);
        boxz.add(rg);
        boxz.add(update);
        boxy.add(boxz);
        scrollPane1.add(boxy);        
    }
```

**EDIT 2**: here is a new test code, but it also does not work:

```
public Fenetre(){
    this.setTitle("Data Simulator");
    this.setSize(300, 300);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    String hello = "hello";
    int number = 69;
    JPanel content = new JPanel();
    content.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    //Box imad = Box.createHorizontalBox();
    JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(10, 10);
    JLabel imad = new JLabel();
    imad.setText(hello + " your favorite number is " + number + "\nRight?");
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(450, 110));

    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    scrollPane.setEnabled(true);
    scrollPane.setWheelScrollingEnabled(true);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(textArea);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(imad);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    //---------------------------------------------
    //On ajoute le conteneur
    content.add(imad);
    content.add(textArea);
    content.add(scrollPane);
    this.setContentPane(content);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setResizable(false);
}
```

A small white scare appears (I think it is the scroll bar or scroll panel?) and the components in the window exceeds the windows size but nothing happens when I try to scroll (using the mouse or by clinking on the white scare). I don't know what is wrong.

Comment: Please update your question with a [minimal, complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: @Radiodef ok it is done.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `scrollPanel.add(boxy)` - you need to add boxy to the scrollPanel's viewport, not to the scrollPanel itself.  Use `scrollPanel.setViewportView(boxy)` instead, or better yet create the ScrollPanel AFTER you create boxy and use the constructor that takes a Component argument.

Comment: It does not work, I have tried a simple code to see if it works (see the new code on my question, I have edited it).
A small white scare appears (I think it is the scroll bar or scroll panel?) and the components in the window exceeds the windows size but nothing happens when I try to scroll (using the mouse or by clinking on the white scare). I don't know what is wrong ! Please see the new code on my question.